# Do Compact Flash cards age?

Tags: storage

I have my CF cards a couple of years now and have always taken for granted that they will store my pictures reliably. But should I? Will there be a time when they suddenly fail? And if so, what are the parameters: Age, amount of read-writes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your CF cards are solid-state flash memory and NOT magnetic (which is probably the case since most CF cards are solid-state), your cards should probably outlive you or me, even if you throw them against the wall every day.  But don't take my word for it, follow the link and read the article.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactFlash :

> CompactFlash cards that use flash memory, like other flash-memory
>   devices, are rated for a limited number of erase/write cycles for any
>   "block." (Read cycles do not cause wear to the device.) Cards using
>   NOR flash had a write endurance of 10,000 cycles. Current cards using
>   NAND flash are rated for 1,000,000 writes per block before hard
>   failure. This is less reliable than magnetic media . . .
>
> Most CompactFlash flash-memory devices limit wear on blocks by varying
>   the physical location to which a block is written. This process is
>   called wear leveling. When using CompactFlash in ATA mode to take the
>   place of the hard disk drive, wear leveling becomes critical because
>   low-numbered blocks contain tables whose contents change frequently.
>   Current CompactFlash cards spread the wear-leveling across the entire
>   drive. The more advanced CompactFlash cards will move data that rarely
>   changes to ensure all blocks wear evenly.
>
> NAND flash memory is prone to frequent soft read errors. The
>   CompactFlash card includes error checking and correcting (ECC) that
>   detects the error and re-reads the block. The process is transparent
>   to the user, although it may slow data access.
>
> As flash memory devices are solid-state, they are more shock-proof
>   than rotating disks. For example, the ST68022CF Microdrive is shock
>   rated at 175G operating and 750G non-operating.

Hope this helps!